# Verify login with Django rest API and react native front end

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am working on building a react native app with a django rest framework backend. I have created the registration ViewSet and have been able to successfully register a user from the front end using the following:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSeralizer
```

I have created another ViewSet to verify the email and password of the user as follows:

```
class LoginViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LoginSeralizer

@detail_route(['POST'])
def login_user(self,request, pk=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email", False)
        password = request.POST.get("password", False)
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                return Response(user.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(user.error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(user.error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The detail_route method is not being called when I try to access the url from the front end. I get a bad response 400 error saying that the user has already been created. Am I on the right track? What changes do I make to the detail_route method so it would be called from the front end when the url is passed into the fetch method of the react native app?

The rest of the files in the django project are as follows:
The url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
#makes sure that the API endpoints work
router.register(r'api/users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'api/login', views.LoginViewSet)
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),]
```

The serializer.py:

```
class UserSeralizer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class LoginSeralizer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined LoginViewSet/LoginSeralizer and UserViewSet/UserSeralizer practically the same. When you login you actually create user.

Read about authentication methods with REST framework:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/